# Не будет ли такой код нагружать систему?

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/5zf4rxqd/

```js
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

 document.onscroll = function(){
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  for(var i = 0; i < block.length; i++){
   if(scrollTop > block[i].offsetTop-window.innerHeight+block[i].offsetHeight-1) block[i].style.background = "red";
  }
 }
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
 #wrap{
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .block {
  background: #34495e;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
 }
 .block:nth-child(2n){
  background: #2c3e50;
  float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут 
  рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот. Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот. Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. 
  <div class="block"></div>
  Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот. 
  <div class="block"></div>
  Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель
  <div class="block"></div>
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот. Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель
  <div class="block"></div>
 </div>
```

циклом перебираются все элементы, если позиция скролла будет больше элемента[i], то...
скажите - такой не будет слишком грубым? понятно, когда 2-3 блока, ну а если их n количество? правильно перебирать все элементы??

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так

Не рекомендую читать offsetTop больше, чем это действительно необходимо, т.к. чтение любых свойств связанных с позиционированием и размерами может вызвать перерисовку как элемента, так и всей страницы (см. [Speed up your JavaScript](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/02/03/speed-up-your-javascript-part-4/))

```js
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

(function(blocks) {
  for (var i = 0, b = null;
    (b = blocks[i]); i++) {
    b.top = b.offsetTop;
  }
})(blocks);

function hilightBlocks() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

  for (var i = 0, b = null;
    (b = blocks[i]); i++) {
    if (scrollTop > b.top - window.innerHeight) {
      b.style.background = "red";
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', hilightBlocks);

hilightBlocks();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrap {
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  background: #34495e;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
.block:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #2c3e50;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми
  правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот. Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста
  по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал
  за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос
  скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную
  страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика
  большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот. Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти
  над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  <div class="block"></div>
  Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь
  своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка
  Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и».
  Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех
  живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо
  в рот.
  <div class="block"></div>
  Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых,
  диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад,
  на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В
  моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель
  <div class="block"></div>
  Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми
  правилами. Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены предложения залетают прямо в рот. Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста
  по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал
  за пояс и пустился в дорогу. Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос
  скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную
  страну». Не послушавшись рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему повстречался коварный составитель
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

PS: на resize окна тоже может быть полезным подписаться ;)